# How to solve : function() is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am trying to use select options to navigate and register params to my URL.
the first thing I want to do is just move to another URL.

I'm facing this problem when I try to use my function with a very simple if condition.
I have an Interface with some names that I say: if this name is = true then onClick go to that URL.

this is the Options HTML snippet :

```
  <select ([ngModel])="clientType" style="width: 15%" class="browser-default custom-select">
     <option selected>Client Type</option>
     <option value="1">MRN</option>
     <option value="2">MRR</option>
     <option value="3">MRE</option>
  </select>
```

This is my method :

```
   onBtnClicked() {
     if(this.clientType.MRR){
      this.router.navigate(['/cont']);
        }
```

this is the button used to call the function :

```
 <a class="btn-floating btn-lg white" id="btn-filter" onclick="onBtnClicked()"><mdb-icon size="4" fas icon="search"></mdb-icon></a>
```

I have tried changing the `this.router.navigate` to `return this.router.navigate` but didn't work.

I have found some things online but it was either explained very oddly, or it didn't belong to my subject

After trying the answers i got i am getting a new Error :

```
cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined
```

Comment: you are assigning selected value in numbers so please try below condition. `if(this.clientType == 2){
      this.router.navigate(['/cont']);
        }` and don't forget to call onBtnClicked on change `<select (change)="onBtnClicked()" ([ngModel])="clientType" style="width: 15%" class="browser-default custom-select">`

Comment: How is `onBtnClicked()` ever called? Is the `<select>` a part of a *Form*?

Comment: @DheerajKumar i cant compare it to a value of int as its an interface.

Comment: Instead of `([ngModel])` should be `[(ngModel)]`

Comment: @EliKnaffo can you please try to print the` clientType value and type of of clientType` in console after change the select value. it might be a comparison error

Comment: @DheerajKumar i changed the values in the Options to match the names i printed the value of clientType first in ngOnInit = undefined . then i printed it in the method and it was changed to MRR but nothing happend when i presses the button

Comment: @EliKnaffo `please change onclick="onBtnClicked()" to (click)="onBtnClicked()" and then try .`

Comment: didn't work the button still does nothing but the value is MRR when i print it to the console log

Answer (score 0):

ngModel should be written like this `[(ngModel)]` and if you want to compare the value of `clientType`, you should do something like this:

```
onBtnClicked() {
  if(this.clientType === '2') { // value of MRR is 1
    this.router.navigate(['/cont']);
  }
}
```

And in your anchor tag, use angular event `(click)` instead of HTML `onclick`:

```
<a class="btn-floating btn-lg white" id="btn-filter" (click)="onBtnClicked()"><mdb-icon size="4" fas icon="search"></mdb-icon></a>
```

Comment: i am getting this error when i put the ==='2' :  This condition will always return 'false' since the types 'ClientType' and '"2"' have no overlap.

Comment: @EliKnaffo I updated my answer. The problem is the ngModel syntax and because of that `clientType` doesn't get the value correctly.

Comment: I have have changed the values to match the names and i am still getting the same error of the condition will always return 'false'

Answer (score 0):

The function `is not defined` because `onclick` is a JavaScript handler and Angular apps are modular. So whatever you call your function it will get a path like `__webpack__.__module__.fn()` or whatever like this.

Instead you should use Angular's `(click)=fn()` to listen for click. Or old fashion way `on-click=fn()`

Comment: i have changed to (click) and it didn't solve the problem. the value is MRR when i check the value in the console log in chrome.

Comment: Your question was about `function is not defined ...` and that question was answered. Further problems is off topic